# Get a list of cities suggestions from text with HERE Geolocation API

Tags: api, rest, geolocation, here-api

I'm trying to find the way to get a list of cities names suggestions from a text written by user. I've managed to do it using the HERE Geocoder Autocomplete API but I would like to use the latest Rest API version Geocoding and Search API v7.

- Does the 7 version substitute the other APIs?
- Is there a way to find cities names suggestions in v7 API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the usage on GS V7 Autosuggest, it can be used for both address and POI, details in [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-autosuggest-brief.html).

For example, API call https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?at=52.5199813,13.3985&limit=5&q=res&apiKey=apiKey will get response like below.
You should be able to parse and get the address from address:city field.

```
    "items": [
    {
        "title": "Hackescher Hof",
        "id": "here:pds:place:276u33db-fb00197ffa5041b2b656ea3d23145dca",
        "resultType": "place",
        "address": {
            "label": "Hackescher Hof, Rosenthaler Straße 40, 10178 Berlin, Deutschland",
            "countryCode": "DEU",
            "countryName": "Deutschland",
            "state": "Berlin",
            "county": "Berlin",
            "city": "Berlin",
            "district": "Mitte",
            "street": "Rosenthaler Straße",
            "postalCode": "10178",
            "houseNumber": "40"
        },
```